# Which is better: many controls or code to arrange the controls?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, performance

I have an app with a form that have a UIScollView with four pages, each page has four control (UITextField, UISlider, UISegmentedControl and Labels). So, twelve controls. Considering the performance of the app, what it is better:

1) Insert the twelve controls in four pages of UIscrollView

2) Insert six control and enough code the arrange it in the same UIView, simulating the changing of pages

3) There is no difference.

Besides, in that app doesn't have only the form but a lot of other things.

Comment: Measure it and let us know!

Comment: You should try and use just 4 controls instead of 12. Just recycle them.

Comment: Could you tell me how to measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3) Performance wise it shouldn't make much of a difference, especially since it's only four pages and twelve controls...that's really nothing resources wise.

However, if you ever forsee adding more pages or controls that need to go to every page it would be smart to code a class that creates the page, rather than create each individual part over and over.  If there are any differences at all you'll want to do each page separate.

Comment: I think that's it. There is no difference. Thanks.